# scrapy shell not opening long link

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm dealing with 
scrapy shell. URL that I'm trying to crawl is: http://allegro.pl/sportowe-uzywane-251188?a_enum[127779][15]=15&a_text_i[1][0]=2004&a_text_i[1][1]=2009&a_text_i[5][0]=950&id=251188&offerTypeBuyNow=1&order=p&string=gsxr&bmatch=base-relevance-aut-1-5-0913

But when I do "view(response)"  I'm getting blank page
Page looks not loaded

```
>>> response.css("title")
[]
```

Now fun part is sometimes it loads properly with same set of commands

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me, I suggest you to start with very basic tutorial:

```
import scrapy

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['http://allegro.pl/sportowe-uzywane-251188?a_enum%5B127779%5D%5B15%5D=15&a_text_i%5B1%5D%5B0%5D=2004&a_text_i%5B1%5D%5B1%5D=2009&a_text_i%5B5%5D%5B0%5D=950&id=251188&offerTypeBuyNow=1&order=p&string=gsxr&bmatch=base-relevance-aut-1-1-0913']

    def parse(self, response):
        print "----------------------------------------------------------------"
        print response.body
        print "----------------------------------------------------------------"
```

I'm able to see the body of the page. `view(response)` is wrong, undefined function.

Save this code as `myspider.py` and run with `scrapy runspider myspider.py`. You will see a big string printing into your terminal, that is the body between `-------------`s.

**For Scrapy Shell:**

Start in shell mode: `scrapy shell`

Just run:

```
>>> fetch("http://allegro.pl/sportowe-uzywane-251188?a_enum%5B127779%5D%5B15%5D=15&a_text_i%5B1%5D%5B0%5D=2004&a_text_i%5B1%5D%5B1%5D=2009&a_text_i%5B5%5D%5B0%5D=950&id=251188&offerTypeBuyNow=1&order=p&string=gsxr&bmatch=base-relevance-aut-1-1-0913")
>>> view(response)
```

It will open scraped page in your default browser. You URL is working for me.

And for title tag it shows:

```
>>> response.css("title")
[<Selector xpath=u'descendant-or-self::title' data=u'<title>Gsxr w Sportowe U\u017cywane - Motocyk'>]
```

Crawled/scraped web page will be saved under `/tmp` directory like `/tmp/tmpn8wziQ.html`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much mertyildiran for help.

scrapy shell is not working for me. Some times it fetch web but for most of times not.I don't know why.

Anyway I end up with code that works great every single time.

import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "allegro"
    start_urls = ['http://allegro.pl/sportowe-uzywane-251188?a_enum%5B127779%5D%5B15%5D=15&a_text_i%5B1%5D%5B0%5D=2004&a_text_i%5B1%5D%5B1%5D=2009&a_text_i%5B5%5D%5B0%5D=950&id=251188&offerTypeBuyNow=1&order=p&string=gsxr&bmatch=base-relevance-aut-1-1-0913']

```
def parse(self, response):
    for lista in response.css("article.offer"):
        yield {
        'link': lista.css('a.offer-title::attr(href)').extract(),            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

just put the link between quotes "" like this:

`scrapy shell "link"`

for your case:

> scrapy shell "http://allegro.pl/sportowe-uzywane-251188?a_enum[127779][15]=15&a_text_i[1][0]=2004&a_text_i[1][1]=2009&a_text_i[5][0]=950&id=251188&offerTypeBuyNow=1&order=p&string=gsxr&bmatch=base-relevance-aut-1-5-0913"